# Access state outside the class

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am updating the width and height values each time the device rotates. I need this values to make some calculations. This is my code

```
function wp (percentage) {
    const value = (percentage * this.state.viewportWidth) / 100;
    return Math.round(value);
}
const height = this.state.viewportHeight * 0.45; // I am getting the error here

export default class MyClass extends Component {

      onLayout(e) {
        this.updateLayout()
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.updateLayout()
      }

      updateLayout = () => {
        const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window')
        this.setState({viewportWidth: width });
        this.setState({viewportHeight: height });
      }
}
```

I am getting an error telling me the `this.state.viewportHeight` is `undefined`. Do you have any idea on how to solve that?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can access the state outside. You need to  make an instance of the class using the new keyword

```
    new MyClass().state.viewportWidth
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use the viewportWidth outside of the component then pass it into your function as a parameter.

```
function wp (percentage, width) {
    const value = (percentage * width) / 100;
    return Math.round(value);
}
```

It is unclear where you are calling the wp function from your code, but if you are calling it from inside the component then you need to replace it with `wp(yourPercentageValue, this.state.viewportWidth)`

You height calculation is just floating there so you can do the same and replace it with a function that takes the viewport

function hp (height) {
        return height * 0.45
    }

Then you can call `hp(this.state.viewportHeight)` in your component.

State, in react, is the state of a component so you can never use it outside of a component. You can pass it into things though, either as a prop or parameter, which is what I did above.

Comment: If that didn't work for you, you need to show us more code to be able to help you. At the moment it is unclear where you are calling the wp function

Answer (score 1):

If your component stays in sync with the dimensions, then outside of your component you could just reference these dimensions directly through:

`Dimensions.get('window').width` and 
`Dimensions.get('window').height`